# Disable Application report for a Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

When I submit a Spark job (on AWS-EMR), I have a lot of "INFO log" on the console:

---

15/02/17 19:44:46 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455192031517_0006 (state: ACCEPTED)

15/02/17 19:44:47 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1455192031517_0006 (state: RUNNING)

:

---

Is there a way to disable these "INFO" ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this INFO message indefinitely when launched spark-shell. Turns to be, one of the Node Managers was in a wrong Role Group with memory allowed way lower than spark-shell has requested (yarn mode). So Spark was waiting for a resource that yarn wasn't able to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the "-l loglevel" argument with the install. See https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/README.md

Or if you are using Spark shell or sql interactively just redirect stderr elsewhere (MASTER=yarn-client ~/spark/bin/spark-shell 2>/tmp/stderr.log).

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```